# Dynamic row selection

Tags: excel, vba

I want to execute a series of code based on row number but want to keep the selection of row number flexible, so that i can execute code for row 15:15, 20:20 etc
here is the code i tried...

```
 Dim i As Integer
  i = 15

Rows("i:i").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("i-1:i-1").Select
Selection.Copy
Rows("i:i").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Rows("i:i").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With Selection.Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range("Ei-1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("Ei-1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+(R[1]C-RC[-1])/2"
Range("Ei").Select
```

Comment: What is your end goal with this? Thought when using variables they must be written out of the `""` for example: `Rows(i).Select` for your first line of code. or `Range("E" & i - 1).Select`

Comment: Try `Rows(i)`. If you put `i` within the quotes, VBA cannot know that you want to refer to the variable `i`, it assumes you want the letter `i`.

Comment: Maybe you're confused from something that works, e.g. `Columns("i:i").Select` would select column "i", but to use `i` as the `Integer` you want you would use `Columns(i).Select` without the "" quotes. In your case you want the row, so use `Rows(i).Select`

Comment: When it comes to using the row number in conjunction with a column, e.g. where you tried `Range("Ei-1").Select` you would use `Range("E" & i - 1).Select` - be careful where you create `Strings` by using `""` quotation marks.

Comment: Better Avoid `Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim i As Long
i = 15
Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows(i - 1).Copy Rows(i)

With Rows(i).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range("E" & i - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+(R[1]C-RC[-1])/2"
```